# Vim-go: Short-cut key to open the files in import?

Tags: go, vim, vim-go

When it comes to vim-cscope, `keyOfOurChoice + f` to open the header files (for the most part) – somehow, I don’t find the answer for this question in https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/wiki/Tutorial#navigate-it

Thanks.

Comment: You might be able to make `gf` or `:find` work; go’s import mechanism is a little harder for vim to parse, i think